# Why my python Armstrong number code doesnt work

Tags: python, list, loops, math, algebra

So ive done an armstrong number code using python and it works fine till the sum of individual digits but after that it doesnt work i will type the code and send a screenshot to show in picture.

```
number = int(input('Enter a number'))
n = len(str(number))
m = s = 0
list1 = []
for i in range(n):
    m = number % 10
    print(m)
    list1.append(m)
    number = number // 10
print(list1)

for o in list1:
    p = o ** n
    s = s + p
    print(s, 'is the sum of nth power of individual terms')

if int(s) == int(number):
    print('It is an armstrong number')
else:
    print('It is not an armstrong number')
```

[image]

I tried to program an armstrong number code for recreational purposes but it doesnt output the way i want it

Comment: your for loops and conditionals are empty, you need to indent your code properly, otherwise it will give you errors

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki. Check the image, it's just a bad copy paste

Comment: then correct the copy paste. answers will be based on the code you post here not on images

Comment: Formatting code is not obvious for a new contributor... You can also edit the post and fix it :-)

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, Im sorry i dont understand u

Comment: @ConTresillo It is not clear what you are expecting from this question. For example your code runs fine when I input number 4, it says 4 is not an Armstrong number. Please remove the screenshot and add the error that you are facing and consider restructuring your question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this

```
number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
original_number = number
n = len(str(number))
s = 0
list1 = []
for i in range(n):
  m = number % 10
  list1.append(m)
  number = number // 10

for o in list1:
  p = o ** n
  s = s + p

if s == original_number:
  print('It is an Armstrong number')
else:
  print('It is not an Armstrong number')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).